# How to correct results from skimage.regionprops

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am using skimage processing to determine the properties of a function that I created and not an image.
First, I created a mesh grid, Second I created a function that I called phi. I plot phi using a contour plot. My phi is simply a circular level set function.
Later, I used labeling method. When phi = 0 is my circular contour, when phi > 0 is inside the circle (I called it Bubble), when phi < 0 is outside the circle.
I did a pyplot contour for what I called it "Bubble" and it looks working!

then I used region props from skimage to determine the properties of the bubble. I am supposed to get the same properties as what I defined in the function phi (radius=0.5, center(2.0, 1.0). However, centroid0 and centroid1 does not have (2.0, 1.0).

Does anyone could help me to figure out how this things work? I know that skimage used directly to an image allows to get properties with region props that need to be corrected with pixel.
In my case, I am not treating an image but directly a function in the plot. So how I can correct the obtained parameters to get logical values?

Here, my code:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
import pandas

#Create a mesh grid
xstart, xend = 0.0, 8.0
ystart, yend = 0.0, 8.0
N = 50
x = numpy.linspace(xstart, xend, N)
y = numpy.linspace(ystart, yend, N)
X,Y = numpy.meshgrid(x,y)

#create a level set function
#radius
r = 0.5
#center
xc = 2.0
yc = 1.0

#level set function
phi = numpy.sqrt((X-xc)**2+(Y-yc)**2) - r

#plot the level set function
width = 10.0
height = (yend - ystart) / (xend - xstart) * width
pyplot.figure(figsize=(width,height))
surf = pyplot.contour(X, Y, phi, rstride=1, cstride=1, levels=[0], linewidth=0)

#labeling
Bubble = phi >= 0

#Plot the label
pyplot.contourf(X,Y,Bubble,levels=numpy.linspace(numpy.min(Bubble),numpy.max(Bubble),10))

#properties using skimage
from skimage import measure
labels = measure.label(Bubble, connectivity=2) 
props  = measure.regionprops_table(labels, properties=['label','area', 'equivalent_diameter', 'centroid', 'perimeter'])
print(props)
BubbleProperties = pandas.DataFrame(props)
print(BubbleProperties.head())
```

The results that I got is:

label  area  equivalent_diameter  centroid-0  centroid-1   perimeter
0      1  2471            56.090774   24.713881   24.641845  218.727922

The result doesn't make sens as my centroid should be (2.0, 1.0) and not (24.71, 24.64) which is situated outside the figure (domain of the figure is [0,8])

Answer (score 0):

The NumPy array `Bubble` does not have any domain information, and by extension neither does regionprops, so the centroid coordinates are in *pixels*, not your units. You need to manually convert between them. In the development version of scikit-image, you can add a `spacing=` parameter to `regionprops_table` to get properties in your choice of units.

Additionally, note that regionprops returns the properties of segments with label > 0. In your case, that is *everything but the bubble*, rather than the bubble. Change the image to `Bubble = phi < 0` to measure what is now the dark area.